# Kinematics problem - Need help solving an integral from a surprisingly difficult problem

Tags: integration, physics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

**I only need to know how to calculate time (t)**, I'll be able to do everything else after that by myself, and I've really tried, **but I reach a hellish integral** (that I've tried to calculate, but my teacher told me that it wasn't the way, his advice was that I should use the initial conditions in a clever way).

I'll upload a picture with clear calculations with all that makes sense. The problem is as follows:

*Knowing that a point mass has an acceleration a(x) = -x - 3x² , find time (t), position ( x(t) ) and velocity ( v(t) ). Initial conditions are:*

*v = 2 m/s when x = -1 m , t = 2 s*

A picture of my progress ---> [Exercice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b5xL.jpg)

I'm not supposed to integrate like a mad man, instead, the teacher told me that there's a clever way to solve v(x) to find time t, but it requires some finesse with calculus and curves.

Many thanks, don't be afraid to throw advanced concepts in order to solve it, I do know differential equations and advanced mechanics. This is a one dimmensional problem from a 1st (introductory) class of physics. Not even Goldsteins mechanics kicked me that hard XD. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: What do you mean by “find time $t$”? Anyway, you have $v^2=3-2x^3-x^2$, so that forces $x \leq 1$ always and $v=0$ only at $x=1$. So at least, your material point is going to go till $x=1$, and then it’s going to accelerate backwards. But as $v$ doesn’t vanish at $x < 1$ (and actually is bounded below in absolute value as $x$ isn’t close to $1$), by the IVT, the speed is alway going to remain negative with bounded below absolute value, so your material point is going to be thrown backwards to infinity. (Not sure how to proceed either, though).

Comment: Kinematics equations are functions of time. But you can treat time (t) like a parameter, and substitute x instead of t in the other two (velocity and acceleration), I'm trying to undo that substitution. I'll give an example so you see what I mean:

$$x=t^3$$So we have $\frac{dx}{dt} =v= 3t^2$ and $\frac{dv}{dt} = a = 6t$
That means $t=x^\frac{1}{3}$ so $v=3x^\frac{2}{3}$ and $a=6x^\frac{1}{3}$

In order to find $t_{(x)}$ you need to reverse (like I did), so once you have time, you can then find $x_{(t)}$, with that, $v_{(t)}$ and $a_{(t)}$

Comment: Here there’s the issue that the problem is invariant under time reversal – but never mind. Another qualitative remark: the integral $(-2x^3-x^2+3)^{-1/2}$ is absolutely convergent on $(-\infty,1)$ so the divergence happens in finite time on both sides.

Comment: I’m a bit puzzled, because Wolfram needs non-elementary functions (elliptic integrals), and complex numbers, to express the result. Is that normal?

Comment: I have no idea, for a 1st year class, that deals with the *introduction* of kinematics, maybe we're overlooking something.
But it's a hard one for sure, bear un mind that the average student in my class doesn't know how to propertly differentiate a $f_{(x)}$ function, and has problems with limits and calculus; this problem requires a solid understanding of calculus and the chain rule, differential equations (separation of variables) and a kickass understanding of what an integral is and how to calculate it, Wolfram won't save you this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${\ddot{x}= -x - 3x²} \\
v\frac{dv}{dx}=-x - 3x² \\
\int_2^v v{dv}=\int_{-1}^x-x - 3x²\ dx \\
\frac{v^2}{2}-2=\frac{-x^2}{2}-x^3+\frac{1}{2}-1 \\
{v^2}={-x^2}-2x^3+{3} \\
{v}=\sqrt{{-x^2}-2x^3+{3}}\\
\int_{-1}^x\frac{dx}{\sqrt{{-x^2}-2x^3+{3}}}=\int_2^tdt$$

This looks not so good but good news is that, the term $2x^3$ has been integrated in the interval of $(-1,x)$, here $x$ never exceeds $1$, this makes the cubic term contribute less. So, we finally get our equation as $$\ddot{x}=-x$$ which is also the equation of S.H.M. or simple harmonic motion.

And upon solving the integral:
$$\int_{-1}^x\frac{dx}{\sqrt{{-x^2}+{3}}}=\int_2^tdt \\
\arcsin \frac{x}{\sqrt3}+\arcsin \frac{1}{\sqrt3}=t-2 \\
{x}={\sqrt3}\sin \left(t-2-\arcsin \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right) \\
\dot{x}={\sqrt3}\cos \left(t-2-\arcsin \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right)$$

Comment: many, many thanks, now I know how to do those kind of problems

Comment: you're welcome. Also, you can mark it as ✓ if it helps you

Comment: **Wait a second.**

If you check the initial conditions, it does check out for the position, *but not for the veolcity*

For t=2s, $x=-1m$ $$\sqrt{3}\sin{(t_2-2-\arcsin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}})}=-1$$ $v=2m/s$ $$\sqrt{3}\cos{(t_2-2-\arcsin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}})}=1.4...\neq2$$

Comment: It's an approximation...Checking the graph, it looks like if instead I approximated $x^2+x^3$ as $2 x^2$ it returns 2 which is perfect. But again at another time "t" there can be an error. If your teacher wrote (x=-0.1) instead -1 the answer would have been incredibly close but again when position x=1, there will be an error

Comment: funny thing: The hellish integral is ~linear in the region (-1,1) the velocity using that curve comes out to be a constant=1.732

Comment: @JoaquinHernandez https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=simplicial.software.Systems You can download this on your android device, it verifies that indeed the motion is harmonic as approximated

Comment: Many thanks, you really really helped me